# Possibility of using high-res image "chunks" using esp32 firmware without PSRAM with ov2640 camera

Tags: image, esp32, bufferedimage, psram, high-resolution

I haven't found any code-base with this specific implementation. I am trying to see whether the implementation of high resolution like 1600x1200 is possible using ov2640 camera with esp32 with only its SRAM, without any external ram like PSRAM. Is it possible to get chunks of image stored in buffer and then store that image in SD card and then free up buffer and get another remaining image and repeat the process again until we get full image in different jpeg and stitch it together using some simple image processing techniques? Curious on what you think of this and whether it is possible or just not feasible with limited memory? I'm asking this here because I tried searching up with this specific keywords but wasn't able to find it.

Let me know if there's any more information you inquire. I'm not using any board right now but want to know whether anybody used this approach before and how did it work out?

Implementation hasn't been tried. It's a theoretical approach that I had, and I want to see if anyone else came across this or not.